# Mount drive not as removable drive

Tags: mount, desktop-environment, removable-storage

I've added the following line to my `/etc/fstab` to mount a ramdisk.

```
none /media/ramdisk tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=2048M 0 0
```

It shows up in my desktop as a removable drive, and it is shown as such in the status bar and in the dock, as shown below.

> [image: Removable drive menu]
> [image: Removable drive in the dock]

How can I disable this? Should I mount it with different options? Do I have to tweak some desktop settings?

I know that I could solve this by disabling the relative extensions, but I want "true" removable drives to show up there.

I don't think its related, but I'm using GNOME 44 on Fedora 38.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`/media` is intended for removable media](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s11.html), which is why your desktop environment shows the mountpoint as removable. To avoid that, mount your file system somewhere else, *e.g.* `/mnt/ramdisk`.